# Code coverage for .net core in linux host

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, code-coverage, xunit

Is there a reliable way of measuring code coverage for .Net Core projects (in particular .Net Core 2) in Linux hosts?

I have looked at [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) and [minicover](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/minicover) but they still have some issues that don't allow me to use them.

Answer (score 6):

VSTest command is working on that issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/981

OpenCover issue: https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/601

[Coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) is the most active project.

Read excellent article of Hanselman: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AutomaticUnitTestingInNETCorePlusCodeCoverageInVisualStudioCode.aspx

[AltCover](https://github.com/SteveGilham/altcover) is also very interesting project that works in .net core.

Comment: I have been testing AltCover lately and it seems to be working fine too.

[https://github.com/SteveGilham/altcover](https://github.com/SteveGilham/altcove)

Comment: added altcover.